# Running sum with gaps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table below with all the columns except for the yellow one

[image]

Basically the table has the ID of the customers, the date the sale happened and total amount spent by the customer that day (Sales). Now I have to calculate the cumulative sales in a time frame per customer in that day including the sales of the day. For example, setting the time frame to 3 day customer 2233 bought twice (nothing on the 14th), so his cumulative sales on the 15th were 26, while on the 13th they were 25.

I can't create new tables so I was trying this approach but it is quite slow

```
SELECT t.dt,

Count(CASE WHEN t.running_sale < 1.99 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Low spender",
Count(CASE WHEN t.running_sale BETWEEN 1.99 and 4.99 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Medium spender",
Count(CASE WHEN t.running_sale > 4.99 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "High spender"

FROM  ( SELECT dt, channel, id, (
     SELECT SUM(revenue)
     FROM  myTable rd
     WHERE CAST(rd.dt AS DATE) 
             BETWEEN (CAST(rd.dt AS DATE) - INTERVAL '3' DAY) AND CAST(rd.dt AS DATE) AND 
           rd.id = r.id 
  ) running_sale from myTable r) t

WHERE channel = 'retail' 
AND dt BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-15'

GROUP BY dt
limit 100
```

Comment: Use an analytic? `sum(Sales) OVER (PARTITION by ID
 ORDER BY Date asc
 ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING ) as RunningSales`

Comment: Doesn't work because will take for theID 2233 in day 12 will take 11 and 06 and that's a gap of more than 3 days.

Comment: I kinda get it but I don't see why the 2233 has 26 on the 15th then if the range is 3 days prior inclusive 15,14,13 this would give 22 not 26. or should the 12'th be included so the range is 15,13,13,12?

Comment: RexTester: for those who want to try it out:http://rextester.com/BJE9775  and my failed attempt)  I suppose we could join it to a numbers table so all dates are included calculated the running sales and filter out those sales with $0...

Comment: Don't focus too much on the example but on the description. I did it manually and that's a typo :D

Comment: How to group 3 dates for a user? It should start from today and go backward or it should start from first date of sale for a particular user?

Comment: Starting today and going backward

Answer (score 2):

I would use a subquery for this

```
select *,
  (
     select sum(sales)
     from your_table dd
     where cast(dd.dates as date) 
             between cast(your_table.dates as date) - interval '3' day and 
                     cast(your_table.dates as date) and 
           dd.id = your_table.id
  ) running_sales
from your_table
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=388ca45abc2cdbefb91caf36a7d6c2a4)

and the above query can be rewritten into a more efficient counterpart that simply uses self-join and `group by`

```
 select dd.id, dd.dates, dd.sales, sum(d.sales) running_sales
 from your_table dd
 join your_table d on cast(d.dates as date) 
         between (cast(dd.dates as date) - interval '3' day) and cast(dd.dates as date) and 
       dd.id = d.id
 group by dd.id, dd.dates, dd.sales
```

[group by demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=02ea90d694a5a17783420ba422fc91d1)

You may consider creating a the following index to support the above query:

```
create index ix_your_table on your_table(id, dates, sales)
```

Comment: Update my question with the full extend that I have to do. Looks like that this method is slow and the server timed out

Comment: @PasqualeSada ok, I have rewritten it into a `group by` version, please test it now and let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE as (
    SELECT 1234 id, '2017-06-15' idate,9 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2233 id, '2017-06-03' idate,20 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2233 id , '2017-06-05' idate,4 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2233 id , '2017-06-06' idate,1 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2233 id , '2017-06-11' idate,8 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2233 id , '2017-06-12' idate,4 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2233 id, '2017-06-13' idate,21 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2233 id, '2017-06-15' idate,1 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2544 id , '2017-06-13' idate,9 sales from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2443 id, '2017-06-05' idate,3.5 sales from dual )

 ,cte2 as (
select cte.*, to_number(replace(idate,'-')) datekey from cte
 )
 --select * from cte2
--SELECT cte.*, sum(cte.Sales) OVER (PARTITION by ID ORDER BY cte.iDate asc ROWS 2 PRECEDING ) as RunningSales FROM CTE

 --select rownum rn from dual connect by prior
 ,pp as (
 SELECT to_number(dd+20170600) dkey
FROM   ( SELECT rownum dd
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31 
       )
)
--select * from pp
,cc as (


select cte2.* ,pp.dkey 
from pp left join cte2 
on(cte2.datekey=pp.dkey)
)
select cc.* ,sum(cc.Sales) OVER (PARTITION by cc.ID ORDER BY cc.dkey asc ROWS 2 PRECEDING ) as RunningSales
from cc order by dkey asc ,id asc
```

Comment: it tests it on oracle 12c. and it works an idea borrows from building data lake dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If there is at most one sale per day, then the most efficient method might be repeated lags:

```
select rd.*,
       (sales +
        (case when prev_date >= date - interval '2 day' then prev_sales else 0 end) + 
        (case when prev2_date >= date - interval '2 day' then prev2_sales else 0 end)
       ) as sales_3day
from (select rd.*,
             lag(date, 1) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date,
             lag(date, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date2,
             lag(sales, 1) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_sales,
             lag(sales, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_sales2
      from mytable rd
) rd;
```

Once you have this value, the rest is just conditional logic on the result.

You can easily make this work if you have multiple sales on one date, by aggregating in the innermost query.